# Vue data not loading for Liquor treeData

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, vue-component

The below code works fine with tree view, because treeData has defined manually. But I need to get data from server app through database dynamically. I read few articles and tried to use, but no success. Someone could give me suggestions. I use Liquor tree.

```
<script>
new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: () => ({
          treeData: null,
          treeOptions: {
            propertyNames: {
              text: 'group_Name',
              children: 'Child',
              state: 'options'
            },
            dnd: true,
            checkbox: true
          }
        }),

    async created() {
    const response = await axios.get('/fields_db')
      .catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response.data);
        }
      })
    console.log(response.data); // i see the data in the console.
    this.treeData = response.data;
})

//app.js
app.get('/fields_db', function(request, response) {
 ......
 response.send(result);
 )}

//html page
<body>      
        <div id='app'>
             <tree 
              :v-if="treeData"
              :data="treeData"
              :options="treeOptions"
            />
        </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: when i set treeData in the init function the treeData is not getting loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lifecycle hook (such as `created`) to asynchronously load async data:

```js
new Vue({
   ...
   data: () => ({
      treeData: null,    // Starts empty
   }),
   async created() {     // async load
     const response = await axios.get(...);
     this.treeData = response.data;
   }
   ...
})
```

Use a `v-if` in the template so that `<tree>` doesn't render before the data is ready:

```html
<tree 
   v-if="treeData"
   :data="treeData"
   :options="treeOptions"
/>
```

(Remove `init` and the DOM `onload`)